# frameit: Why is iPhone's 4 frame discontinued?

Tags: ios, iphone, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I am using [frameit](https://github.com/fastlane/frameit) to add frames to my iOS screenshots, before uploading to the App Store. When it is the time for the iPhone 4S screens, I get the following error:

```
Unfortunately 3.5" device frames were discontinued.
```

Quite straightforward, however: Why is this? Is this mandatory from Apple, or can I just get my own frames (instead of the [Apple-provided](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#images) frames) and use them in the App Store? Will my app get rejected if I do this?

thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3.5" resources are not provided by Apple any more, that's why `frameit` warns you that it's not supported.